# How To Get Data From Gridview

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I want to ask, how to get / set data from 2 gridview like example from Screenshoot..?
If I press Button 'PROCESS', Then i want to set 1 Data from Gridview 1, will get 5 data from gridview 2.

in this case i use Devexpress Gridcontrol and Vb.Net Program Language.

[image: example Picture]

Comment: Do you want the KODE to be all zeroes or you want to increment it starting from the KODE in the left grid?

Comment: Column KODE in Grid 2, Not Increment or Relate with Column KODE in Grid 1.
Let us ignore advance about it.

in this case,,
i want to set Result Like :

-  PETUGAS 0  ----> Get 5 Data  :  (REG 0,REG 1,REG 2,REG 3,REG 4)
-  PETUGAS 1  ----> Get 5 Data  :  (REG 5,REG 6,REG 7,REG 8,REG 9)

And will Continue until The Last PETUGAS.

How i can Make it by Code.?
please Help,
Thank's...